# Is Angular http request call when a variable scope change?

Tags: http, angularjs

I have to use a http get request in my angular script where I have to send some variables to the server. 
My question is if the sending variable is changed somehow, then will the request call again automatically?, or do I have to call the request again??

Thanks

updated: 
code in my controller:

```
$scope.startDate = "";

$http.get('/Controller/Action', {startDate: $scope.startDate}).success(data){
       alert(data)
}
```

if somehow the value of the startDate is changed will the http request be called again or I have to place it into a watch.

Comment: The question is not clear. What you mean by the variable change here?

Comment: What will happen depends on the code. The code matters. Without seeing the code, we can't explain what it will do.

Answer (score 3):

While the question is unclear, I believe what you are referring to is a $watch setup on a scope property. If you make a normal request, such as this:

```
$scope.myResource = 'path/to/resource'; //could be used use without $scope for this example
$http.get($scope.myResource) //etc
```

the call is just made once, because that's all it is told to do. If you want it to update when the path "myResource" changes, then do this:

```
$scope.$watch('myResource', function(newPath) { //watching $scope.myResource for changes
  $http.get(newPath) //etc
})
```

Now, when the value of `$scope.myResource` changes, the $http call will be again, this time requesting the new path.

Comment: why doesn't angjs detect changes to `myResource` and call `$http.get($scope.myResource)` again? if it were a `$scope.var = $scope.myResource`, `var` would be updated too

Comment: @Blauhirn That's what `watch` does. The controller function is executed once and describes how the application works. `$scope.var = 123` is a one time setting of a variable. There's nothing about it that describes updating.